# ¿Como utilizar el mismo request para agregar o actualizar registros en laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel

Hola paso a explicar detalladamente mi caso. Estoy aprendiendo laravel eh realizado un crud con dos tablas relacionadas una de users y otro medicos.
La tabla users esta estructurada asi:

| id | name | username | email | password |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | Pedro | test | test@hotmail.com | password |

Donde id es la columna relacionada con la tabla medicos que esta estructurada asi

| id_medicos | dni | direccion | telefonos | id_usuarios |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 712727 | calle 9393 | 934934943 | 28 |

Donde id_usuarios recibe el valor id de la tabla users.

Tengo este request que lo eh utilizado para agregar registros

```
 public function rules(): array
    {
        $id = $this->route('medico'); 
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users,username,' . $id,

            'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,' . $id,
            'password' => 'required',
            'cedula' => 'required',
            'direccion_medicos' => 'required',
            'telefonos' => 'required',
            //  'id_usuarios' => 'required',

        ];
    }
```

Con lo que hice esto  `$id = $this->route('medico');` saco el id proviente de la url del medico a editar y en efecto lo consigo pero al mandar a actualizar no me ingnora la condicional `unique` en username, y email. Por lo que no consigo hacer un update ya que siempre que envio el formulario me sale que username y correo ya estan registrados como podria solucionar esto.

Finalmente tendria el controlador update que seria para actualizar los datos

```
 public function update(MedicosRequest $request, $id)
    {

        $medicos = Medicos::findOrFail($id);
        $medicos->update($request->validated());
        try {
            $medicos->update($request->validated());

            // Obtener el modelo "Users" relacionado
            $user = $medicos->users;

            // Actualizar los datos en tabla usuarios
            $user->fill([
                'name' => $request->name,
            ]);
            $user->save();

            $mensaje = 'Medico editado correctamente';
            return redirect('/test/' . $id . '/edit')->with('success', $mensaje);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Sin olvidar el modelo de medicos

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class Medicos extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'cedula',
        'direccion_medicos',
        'telefonos',
        'id_usuarios'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_medicos';

    //crea metodo mostrar datos tabla relacionada usuarios - medicos

    /* public function users(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'id_usuarios');
    }
 */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_usuarios', 'id');
    }
}
```

Cualquier recomendación lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Si en la variable `$id` tienes la id del medico a editar, ten en cuenta que en tu regla estas queriendo validar el username y email en la tabla `users` (y no en la de medicos). Por lo que tendrías que obtener el id del user, y no del medico, para que se ignore esa regla en el caso de un update

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta ya veo. Tratare de tomar ese enfoque si no hay mas solucion

Comment: Creo que lo mas facil ahí, sería usar el modelo (y la propiedad que corresponde a la fk) en vez de la tabla y columna de la BD. Fijate en el primer ejemplo de la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: O algo asi `$user_id = Medicos::find($this->route('medico'))->id_usuarios;` para luego hacer `'username' => 'required|unique:users,username,' . $user_id,`